# Search files in a certain period and copy them into another directory

Tags: linux, centos, find

The problem is that I have a directory containing many files with extensions *.xml*, *.txt* and *.p7m* from year 2015 up today.

I must create a script that searches into the directory `1` all files created in a time interval, for example: from `13-jan-2016 to 23-feb-2016`, and then perform a copy of these files found in that period in a subdirectory `2` and if it finds a duplicate it must rename that file as *duplicate_namefile_ori*.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue the following command:

```
find dir1/ -type f -newermt "2016-01-13" ! -newermt "2016-02-23"  -exec cp -b -S _duplicate  '{}' dir2 \;
```

it will copy the files in `dir1` with *modification time* between 2016-01-13 and 2016-02-23 to `dir2`and appending the **suffix** *_duplicate* to the duplicate files in the destination directory.

If you need to do it with  *creation time* the use `-newerBt` instead of  `-newermt`.  `ext4` as most of unix/linux filesystems doesn't store the creation time of the files, so it won't work on Ext4 / Linux.

You can check which timestamps are being stored with the command `stat <filename>`.

Comment: Thank s for your reply jcbermu but I must work with the creation time and not with modification time...is this the same?

Comment: @GianfilippoEvola I added information in the answer to let you know about creation time.

Comment: sorry I know but I do some test and when I run my script for period from 2016-06-01 to 2016-06-03 I have only 2016-06-01 result and nothing else...I don t understand the reason